# getChildHtml function overwrites languages translations

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, phtml, view

I've a great problem with languages translations of many words of my multilanguages site in Magento 1.9.
I noticed that getChildHtml function overwrites many languages transations contained in translate.csv.
E.g.:

```
<fieldset class="product-options" id="product-options-wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true);?>
</fieldset>
```

With this phtml string

```
"size guide", "tailles"
```

is overwritten.

How can I modify the code to have correct translations?
Can you help me, please?